# Access file from subfolder of s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, client

I need to access a file and print its content from a subfolder in an s3 bucket. My file (file_abc) is in a sub folder (subfolder_abc) in a folder (folder_abc) in s3 bucket.

I am using the following code to do so -

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='Bucket_abc',
                                    Key='folder_abc/subfolder_abc' + "/" + 'file_abc')
result = str(response["Body"].read())
print (result)
```

I am getting the following error -

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetObject operation: Access Denied
```

How to access data of files in subfolders?

Comment: The error says `Access Denied`. This means that you do not have permission to access the requested object. Have you assigned the necessary permissions to the IAM credentials (eg IAM User or IAM Role) that is being used by the code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the permissions for the bucket?

The way you are attempting to read the file looks correct, I assume you have an issue with the permissions for reading files in that bucket.

If you can show us the permissions for the bucket and the role you function is executing as, we can be of more help.

Here is a policy example that would allow all access:

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
     }
   ]
  }
```